# Escolhas de datas

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde galera,

Estou querendo fazer um `iif` no sql de que se o campo `FLAG` for igual a "*E*" ele traga a data da coluna `DTDIGIT` e armazene na variável `@dataInicio`, e quando o `FLAG` for "*S*" ele traga a data da coluna `EMISSAO` e armazene na variável `@dataFIM`.

Para depois eu declarar essas variáveis, pois essa _ query_ irá se tornar uma função.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O campo FLAG está armazenado onde? O que é um campo, neste contexto? Observe que no enunciado é citado tanto "campo" quanto "coluna". // Como é a tabela de origem? // Como estão declaradas as colunas DTDIGIT e EMISSAO?

Comment: Bom dia o campo flag é uma coluna que o unico resultado dele é E ou S (entrada ou saída) a coluna emissao e dtdigit sãio do tipo date,

Comment: Seria algo  +/- assim   
IIF (FLAG = 'E' , DTDIGIT OR FLAG = 'S'EMISSAO)

Answer (score 0):

Se houver uma única linha com a coluna FLAG contendo "S" e outra linha contendo o valor "E", ambas atendendo ao filtro definido na cláusula WHERE, o código abaixo retorna o que é solicitado.

```
-- código #1
SELECT @dataInicio= case when FLAG = 'E' then DTDIGIT else @dataInicio end,
       @dataFim= case when FLAG = 'S' then EMISSAO else @dataFim end
  from tabela
  where ...;
```

Exemplo:

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE Config (FLAG char(1), DTDIGIT date, EMISSAO date);

INSERT into Config values
  ('E', '20120303', NULL), ('S', NULL, '20120403');

declare @dataInicio date, @dataFim date;

SELECT @dataInicio= case when FLAG = 'E' then DTDIGIT else @dataInicio end,
       @dataFim= case when FLAG = 'S' then EMISSAO else @dataFim end
  from Config;

SELECT @dataInicio, @dataFim;
```

Entretanto, se houver mais de uma linha com o mesmo valor para a coluna FLAG, o preenchimento das variáveis é indeterminado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu acho que seu case nao está filtrando
tentei fazer algo +/- assim  WHERE     IIF(FLAG = 'E', DTDIGIT, EMISSAO) < '20180101'
Mas agora to na duvida como  colocar nas variaveis para a pessoa escolher de quando a quando quer as informações referente as datas

Comment: Será útil se, no enunciado do tópico, você acrescentar amostra dos dados bem como resposta esperada para a amostra.

Comment: Vou te mandar a query

Comment: SELECT FN.COMPANY, 
    FN. FILIAL, 
    FN.DOC NOTA_FISCAL,    
    ISNULL (A2.A2_COD,A1_COD) [COD FORNECEDOR],
    ISNULL (A2.A2_NOME,A1_NOME) [ NOME FORNECEDOR],
    FN.TIPO,
    FN.NFORI NOTA_DE_ORIGEM,
    FN.CUSTO1 CUSTO,
    FNI.NUMSERI,
    P.COD COD_PRODUTO,
    P.DESCR DESCRICAO_PRODUTO,
    O.OPERACAO,
    O.DESCRI DESCRICAO_OPERACAO,
    CAST(FN.EMISSAO AS datetime)DATA,
    FN.FLAG
    --IIF (FLAG = 'E' , DTDIGIT  FLAG = 'S',EMISSAO)
FROM TLX_NFI_ENTRADASAIDA FN

 WHERE     IIF(FLAG = 'E', DTDIGIT, EMISSAO) < '20180101'

Comment: No SQL Server não é possível, em uma mesma instrução SELECT, retornar resultados e ao mesmo tempo assinalar valores para variáveis.